Where to find jdk sources for JNI_CreateJavaVM?
I'm trying to understand better how jvm works, and I was trying to find the main function that really interested me - the JNI_CreateJavaVM function. I wonder how it parses java bytecode, but I can't find where's the function defined anywhere.
I searched in github repository but I can't find it anywhere, there's so much folders.  I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in hotspot though.

I'd look at openjdk on Github first and search for this function. Depending on the platform you're interested in, you'll find the right implementation. This would be the Windows implementation.

Yes, that's exactly where I was looking. I'm looking for implementation on windows. There'a file called jvm.dll which jli.dll uses to create a java virtual machine, but it just exports it from the dll. I am not really familiar with github, so I don't really understand how this search function works. I searched my function in different folders but never could find it.

@stavratum Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/49eb00da8dc66cff3ca430f06ab21357ee6180ef/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp#L3666

Yes! Thank you so much

@stavratum if it helped, consider accepting my answer
